# Will changing `auto_increment_increment` and `auto_increment_offset` on production environment MySQL database cause any error?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-rds, mysql-5.6

I'm following [this article](https://workmarket.tech/zero-downtime-maintenances-on-mysql-rds-ba13b51103c2) to create a master-to-master replication on Amazon RDS.

The master and slave MySQL servers are both created using Amazon RDS.

One thing I'm concerned about is whether changing [`auto_increment_increment`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) and [`auto_increment_offset`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset) of the production environment database will cause any error to the production database or not.

The [official document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) says that they are used to control the operation of AUTO_INCREMENT columns. So I'm worried that this will affect the existing production database.

Has anyone ever changed these values and generated any error?

Comment: I'd recommend using row-based replication, so the id will be generated on the master, then the row images will be replicated verbatim. The AI options will not matter.

Comment: @BillKarwin with circular replication, setting these properly allows you to avoid auto-increment collisions if both masters take an insert at the same time.

Comment: Thank you, I am familiar with those variables.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [Replication and Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-features-variables.html) these variables are automatically replicated to slaves.

So if you set them on the master, the slaves should pick up the changes, and they'll assign auto increment IDs the same as the master.

Note that this is only an issue when using statement-based replication. If you use log-based replication, the IDs that the master assigns will automatically be replicated.